# Authentication with Google Calendar API using Server Account and .NET

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm using Google Calendar API V3, with OAuth2 & .NET.
my authentication is by Service Account, since i need to run it as a service, without user interface.
I've managed, after a lot of struggle to authenticate with the credentials, but for some reason i can't create an event on my calendar (& yes, i shared it with my self...).

i found a lot of questions regarding some same issues, but all in php, which i don't really know or think it will help me.

i seek for some help. Thanks

```
    String serviceAccountEmail = "XXX@developer.gserviceaccount.com";

            var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"key.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet |X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
            ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
               new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
               {
                   Scopes = new[] { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar }
               }.FromCertificate(certificate));

            // Create the service.
            var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {                    
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "Calendar API Sample",
            });

            Event e = new Event()
            {
                Summary = "Appointment1",
                Location = "42.138679, -88.045519",
                Start = new EventDateTime()
                {
                    DateTime = DateTime.Now,
                    TimeZone = "Asia/Jerusalem"
                },
                End = new EventDateTime()
                {
                    DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
                    TimeZone = "Asia/Jerusalem"
                },
            };

            Event createdEvent = service.Events.Insert(e, "primary").Execute();
```

Comment: I have been struggling with Google .NET library as well. The API seems good but it as a few problems 1) Every release seems to totally break the last version and 2) There are no good sample applications, just code snippets that dev's need to jigsaw together.

Comment: 1. There were broken changes while the library was BETA. But, now that had reached GA there won't be any incompatible changes. 2. 
There are few samples in our samples repository - https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse?repo=samples. Remember that this is an open source project so it will be great if you will share a sample in the future.

Comment: Not many breaking changes since beta, but many breaking changes since version 1.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, the Insert event to a "primary" calendar, didn't do the job.
Instead, i wrote the following code, which allowed me to write the event.

```
var list = service.CalendarList.List().Execute().Items;
service.Events.Insert(e, list[0].Id).Execute();
```

This is my solution for this problem, I also agree with Craig here that the API is not well organized. (saying this after working with the amazing API of maps).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try specifying the user programmatically, rather than sharing the calendar with your service account e-mail? The following worked in my application:

```cs
ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
    new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
    {
        User = "youremail@yourdomain.com",
        Scopes = new[] { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar }
    }.FromCertificate(certificate));

// ... Define the event    

service.Events.Insert(e, "primary").Execute();
```